# Using application(\_)profile for GIT placeholders in spring boot cloud config service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

The  [Spring Boot cloud config server docs](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#environment-repository) say you can use placeholders in your GIT URL for {application} and {profile}.  Further, they mention support for a **"organization(\_)application"** style where the **(\_)** is a placeholder for a slash.

I cannot get this to work. Further, I can't find in the source where such a case is even handled. Even a unit test would be useful to look at. Can someone show me some example code or a test that shows how to properly use this feature?

Comment: How are you storing your configuration files?  In Git?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty much following the examples in the manual for GIT URL token support.